# Changing console font size in Windows XP

Tags: python, console-application

I am trying to change the console font size using the program below.

```
import ctypes

LF_FACESIZE = 32
STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11

class COORD(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("X", ctypes.c_short), ("Y", ctypes.c_short)]

class CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("cbSize", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("nFont", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwFontSize", COORD),
                ("FontFamily", ctypes.c_uint),
                ("FontWeight", ctypes.c_uint),
                ("FaceName", ctypes.c_wchar * LF_FACESIZE)]

def changefont():
    font = CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX()
    font.cbSize = ctypes.sizeof(CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX)
    font.nFont = 12
    font.dwFontSize.X = 30
    font.dwFontSize.Y = 30
    font.FontFamily = 54
    font.FontWeight = 400
    font.FaceName = "Lucida Console"

    handle = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(
            handle, ctypes.c_long(False), ctypes.pointer(font))

changefont()
print "Hello world"
```

The programm is turned into an executable using

```
pyinstaller --onefile demo.py
```

Execution of the final program works well for Win7 systems, I get a console with changed font size.

However, doing the same on an old Windows XP laptop, I get an

```
AttributeError: function 'SetCurrentConsoleFontEx' not found
```

Something is different there, but I don't know what it is and I have no idea where to start. Any input appreciated.

Comment: Looks like XP doesn't have a `SetCurrentConsoleFontEx` function.

Comment: Ah yes, that's what I figured out with my limited knowledge ;-). My question would then be is there a way to make it have one, or is there another way to change font sizes for the console in Windows XP? Probably not that many old PCs around where users could help ... Do you knwo in which library or dll that function would be located?

Comment: When I was using XP, I just changed the properties of `cmd.exe` and specified the font and size that way. If you don't want it that way all the time, you can create separate shortcuts to `cmd.exe` and specify different properties for each one.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was aware of that possibility and used it myself. However, I want to do this from within the programm, since this program is intended for distribution to other users.

Comment: [`SetCurrentConsoleFontEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is only supported by Vista or later. A workaround for XP might be to find out where in the Registry Windows stores the font and size to be used for the cmd console and change it. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Console` looks like it would be a good place to start. I think XP only allowed monospaced fonts to be used.